# Can't send attachments from application

Tags: android

I am trying to send a PDF from my application but when I tap "Send" it does not get attached it seems. I can see the icon for the file in the mail application though.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mailSubject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mailMessage);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/download_l.pdf"));
```

Comment: Is the `download_l.pdf` in your app's `/assets` directory?

Answer (score 0):

The type should be "application/pdf" rather than "message/rfc822"

From the ACTION_SEND documentation:

> Input: getType() is the MIME type of the data being sent. get*Extra
>   can have either a EXTRA_TEXT or EXTRA_STREAM field, containing the
>   data to be sent. If using EXTRA_TEXT, the MIME type should be
>   "text/plain"; otherwise it should be the MIME type of the data in
>   EXTRA_STREAM. Use */* if the MIME type is unknown (this will only
>   allow senders that can handle generic data streams).

In addition, I don't think you can attach something directly from your assets. I believe you have to copy to the SD card first and then send it from there